# FirebaseRecycleAdapter with Glide(or Picasso) load image in wrong place

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I use FirebaseRecycleAdapter to load chat data from Firebase RealtimeDatabase. 
I want to show the message on two way, so the left image different the right image.

But the image sometimes misplace like the picture.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
                Message.class,
                R.layout.item_message_onetoone,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                databaseReference.child(Constant.CHILD_CHATONETOONE).child(myUid).child(clientUid)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message message, int position) {
                String senderUid= message.getSenderUid();

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.leftMargin= 10;
                lp.rightMargin= 10;

                viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(message.getMessage());
                if (senderUid.equals(myUid)){
                    lp.gravity= Gravity.RIGHT;
                    viewHolder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    Glide.with(OneToOneConversationActivity.this).load(myPhotoURL).into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
                    viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(myName);

                }
                else if(senderUid.equals(clientUid)){
                    lp.gravity= Gravity.LEFT;
                    viewHolder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);


                    viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(clientName);

                }

            }
        };
```

MessageViewHolder class:

```
public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageTextView;
        public TextView messengerTextView;
        public CircleImageView messengerImageView;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
            messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
            linearLayout= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llOneToOneChat);
        }
    }
```

The linearlayout and textViews works fine exept CircleImageView. It seems like context: OneToOneChatActivity.this when i use code : Glide.with(....) is wrong, but I cant figure out solution.
How can I make it work property?

Comment: try using else instead of else if

Comment: @elmontoya7 there is no change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. There is two way to solve the problem

- One:
  Use solution in this post: [Android, Glide shows wrong image for about one second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251009/andorid-glide-shows-wrong-image-for-about-one-second/38251171#38251171)

so in this post, in "else" case, you can set a transparent color to imageView to avoid the problem

- Two:
  You can use two library to load these images, for example: Glide and Piccaso.